# How to have a global property changed event handler with KnockoutJS

Tags: events, knockout.js, propertychanged

I come from a C# environment, there we have INotifyPropertyChanged interface. When subscribed to this property changed event, one receives the sender, and the property name. The sender is the ViewModel in this example. I want to have something similar with KnockoutJS. I tried to subscribe and store the instance of the function to a hashtable which contains an object with ViewModel and PropertyName parameter. Because the new value in the observable isn't sufficient for what I want to use the event for.

How can I create code with KO that works in a similar fashion as C#'s INotifyPropertyChanged?

This is some crap I wrote to show you I've put in some effort. But I am failing here miserably.

```
var propertyChangedHashTable = new Hashtable();

function PropertyChanged(newValue) {
    console.log(this);
    var changedEventParams = propertyChangedHashTable[this];
    console.log(changedEventParams);
    //gateway.propertyChanged(changedEventParams.viewModel, changedEventParams.propertyName, newValue);
};

function subscribePropertyChanged(viewModel, objectPath) {
    if (typeof objectPath === "undefined" || objectPath == null) objectPath = "";
    if (objectPath.length !== 0) objectPath += '.';
    var observable = ko.observable("").toString();

    for (var propertyName in viewModel) {
        var viewModelName = viewModel.__proto__.constructor.name;
        var localObjectPath = objectPath + viewModelName;
        var property = viewModel[propertyName];
        if (propertyName.indexOf("ViewModel") !== -1) {
            subscribePropertyChanged(property, localObjectPath);
            continue;
        }
        var isObservable = property.toString() === observable.toString();
        if (!isObservable) continue;

        var propertyChangedFunc = PropertyChanged;

        propertyChangedHashTable.put(propertyChangedFunc, 'test');
        property.subscribe(propertyChangedFunc);
    }
}

function MainViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.isRecording = ko.observable(false);
    self.dataDirectory = ko.observable("C:\\Temp\\Recordings");
    self.toggleIsRecording = function() {
         self.isRecording(!self.isRecording());
    };
}

var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
subscribePropertyChanged(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the knockout [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

> The subscribe function accepts three parameters: callback is the function that is called whenever the notification happens, target (optional) defines the value of this in the callback function, and event (optional; default is "change") is the name of the event to receive notification for.

So if you supply the ViewModel as second argument "target" to `subscribe()` you can access it in the handler as `this`. For example:

```
<p data-bind="text: counter"></p>
<button data-bind="click: buttonClicked">Increment</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.counter = ko.observable(0);
    this.buttonClicked = function() {
        this.counter(this.counter() + 1);
    };

    this.counter.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
        console.log(this);
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```